# Insert into table - Error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'md5'

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I'm trying to build a php form that will insert users into users table.
User name and User email will be entered manually via a HTML form and User Password will be generated randomly at the same time.
This is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
require_once 'dblogin.php'; 

  $OK = false;
  $conn = new mysqli ($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Connection Failed");
  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();


  $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_name, user_password)
          VALUES(?, ?, des_encrypt(substring (md5(rand(),1,8))))';
  if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    // bind parameters and execute statement
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password']);
    // execute and get number of affected rows
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
      $OK = true;
    }
  }
  if ($OK) {
    header('Location: confirm.php');
    exit;
  } else {
    $error = $stmt->error;
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add User</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Add User</h1>
<?php if (isset($error)) {
  echo "<p>Error: $error</p>";
} ?>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="user_email">User email:</label>
    <input name="user_email" type="text" class="widebox" id="user_email">
  </p>
    <p>
    <label for="user_name">User name:</label>
    <input name="user_name" type="text" class="widebox" id="user_name">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Register New User" id="insert">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I'm getting is: Error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'md5'. I'm a beginner and I have never used md5, could someone please help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here :

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_name, user_password)
          VALUES(?, ?, des_encrypt(substring (md5(rand(),1,8))))';
```

MD5 takes only one parameter - the string to be hashed.

Try this :

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_name, user_password)
          VALUES(?, ?, des_encrypt(substring(md5(rand()),1,8)))';
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this but it gives this error: Error: FUNCTION testing.substring does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: avoid the space between `SUBSTRING` and the parenthesis containing its parameters. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Don't add a space between the function name and the parenthesis containing its parameters. It is not allowed in SQL.

Comment: great that works perfect, although I have an another issue in the php form now, not sure if you can help it give this error: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: for this line: $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password']);

Comment: @elmify you said that the  password will be randomly generated. Then why `$_POST['user_password']` ? You have two `?` in your query and your passing 3 variables in `bind_param` call. Either remove `$_POST['user_password']` or change the query to `INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_name, user_password) VALUES(?, ?, des_encrypt(?))`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do this...

```
SUBSTRING( MD5( RAND( ) ) , 1, 8 )
```

Instead of

```
substring (md5(rand(),1,8))
```

Your query should be like this...

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_name, user_password)
      VALUES (?, ?, DES_ENCRYPT( SUBSTRING( MD5( RAND( ) ) , 1, 8 ) ) )';
```

Comment: thanks, when I tried this it said:  Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'rand'. I'm trying to randomise a password with 8 characters

Comment: cheers ! I get this error: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement      for this line:$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_password']); Am I not supposed to use 's' for user_password ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used mysqli .. but, the error is 'incorrect param count'.. if you look at your code:

`(user_email, user_name, user_password)` - thats 3 columns
and
`(?, ?, des_encrypt(substring (md5(rand(),1,8))))` .. 3 columns

vs:

`$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_role'], $_POST['user_password']);` . . 4 params..

Remove the `'sss'` ?

Also, looking at the matching, as it is, once u remove the `'sss'` your still going to be posting:
user_email = $_POST['user_email'] 
user_password = $POST['user_role'] . .

So you need to make it

`` `$stmt->bind_param($_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_name']); ``